# Accessing classes in vectors

Tags: c++, vector

This question has been asked before so many times, but I do exactly what the answers say, and they all give syntax errors.

I tried multiple methods, this is just the last one I tried.

```
vector<Ent*>World;
// other code here
for( vector<Ent*>::iterator i = World.begin();
        i != World.end(); ++i )
    {
        World[i]->GetID();
    }
```

Comment: In C++11 you can do `for(auto ent : World) ent->GetID();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong syntax.

```
World[i]->GetID();
```

`i` is an iterator, not an integer index.

Use

```
(*i)->GetID();
```

Answer (score 3):

For vectors, the [] operator is an index accessor that you use when you want to access an element as an index (i.e. a number) into the container e.g.:

```
for( int i = 0;
    i < World.size(); ++i )
{
    World[i]->GetID();
}
```

You on the other hand are using iterators. The iterator object itself refers to the elements of the container, so you have to change your syntax:

```
for( vector<Ent*>::iterator i = World.begin();
    i != World.end(); ++i )
{
    (*i)->GetID();
}
```

Note that iterators provide you a pointer-like interface to the element which is why you have to dereference it first (*i) before you access the member.